# How do I stop Windows File Browser from resetting the "show all folders" and "expand to current folder"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems

One of my computers has an annoying issue which resets the navigation panel on Windows File Browser. It always sets to "Show all folders" and "Expand to current folder", flooding the navigation panel with a massive amount of folders.

Every time I uncheck those settings, it only lasts while I am logged in. Even if I leave my computer idle and come back (log back in) it is then reset.

I see no other options or settings which triggers this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, Windows Explorer view are never really permanent.

However, in this case, do the following.

Restart your computer (for a fresh start).
Open Windows Explorer, View, Options and click on Reset Folders.

Now close Windows Explorer.

Re-open Windows Explorer.

Go to a top level folder and make sure folders are closed except for the main root.

Now, View Tab, Options, View tab within Options, set your various views.

Now, click on Apply to Folders.

This should work fairly well.

Should you need a permanent view for the work you do, I do this with xPlorer2 (Zabkat)